# Obtain dates with JavaScript before AJAX request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this AJAX request:

```
function request(str){
    <script>      
    var aircraft = $("#div");
        aircraft.load("./file.php?icao="+str, function(){
        });
    }
<script>
<div id="div"><div>
```

When I execute this option. Request to the file.php

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#submit")
            .button()
            .click(function form() {
        });
    });

    function form(){

        var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
                $("div2").text(id);
    }
</script>
<div id="div2"><div>
<tr><td class="forms">ID:</td><td><input maxlength="4" type="text" id="id" name="icao" size="30"/></td></tr>

<tr><td><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
```

When I press the button there isn´t a result. The value of var id is undefined. The problem is in the function request. Because if I do directly without the function all works fine. I think is a problem with the AJAX and the Javascript after.

Comment: Is the second piece of code the content of the PHP file you are loading, and are you expecting the javascript in that loaded file to run ???

Comment: Yes, I need the Javascript in the 2nd file!

Comment: The question was; are you loading the javascript in the second example with ajax ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function form() {
    var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
    $("div2").text(id);
}

$(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
      form();
    });
});
```

The syntax for embedding a function call in a jQuery event was incorrect. If you want to execute another function inside a jQuery function, you have to do the above, not `.click(function form() {});`

Comment: ... or just pass "form" directly, since it doesn't need any parameters.

Comment: What happens if you try updated answer (without `button()` method)

Comment: If it where my answer, I would consider the fact that a submit button probably should have something to prevent it's default action, and as Pointy pointed out (pun intended) , you can just do : `$("#submit").on('click', form);`

Comment: From what I understand, all the OP wants to do is intercept the request, change a form value, and allow the original form submission to go ahead. I don't think `preventDefault()` behaviour would benefit the scenario

Comment: -1. Although the code doesn't look great, the OP stated that it works okay when used directly.

Comment: @Jack Where? Provide me a direct quotation. He also said that `id` was not defined - most likely because he was firing the `form()` function incorrectly, which I addressed.

Comment: @Jamie From the question `... Because if I do directly without the function all works fine ...`

Comment: @Jack That's completely ambiguous - the OP could be referring to three erroneous functions. I solved two of them - you focused on the obvious `<script>` tag error. Absolutely no reason for a downvote or argument.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but shouldn't the `<script>` tag come before the function?

```
<script>    
function request(str){    
    var aircraft = $("#div");
        aircraft.load("./file.php?icao="+str, function(){
        });
}
<script>
```

Comment: Yeah, but it isnt the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is broken:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#submit")
            .button()
            .click(function form() {
        });
    });

    function form(){

        var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
                $("div2").text(id);
    }
</script>
```

Not sure that this will totally fix it but I think this is the right syntax:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#submit")
            .button()
            .click(function() {
                 form();
        });
    });

    function form(){

        var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
                $("div2").text(id);
    }
</script>
```

I don't think this will solve your problem though but that syntax you were using wasn't formed right. I think instead of calling the function like this:

```
form();
```

You may also be interested in looking at .trigger() or .call(), I also looked at the jquery documentation and I have never seen .button(), what is that for?

Comment: Ok, this don´t solved the problem. Please, help me to solve the problem. I think it is in the request function!