# Put a Javascript var converted to PHP in a <div>

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript after Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417862/javascript-after-ajax)

I want to use Javascript code in a DOM.

I have this request:

```
function ajaxrequest(str){

    var aircraft = $("#resultdiv");
        aircraft.load("./file.php?icao="+str, function(){
        });
    }
```

And I have this javascript code in the file.php:

```
<script>
    function example(){

            var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
                    $("div2").text(id);
        }
    </script>
```

How Can I do the Javascript out a DOM and correctly? If I do this in the DOM. `var id = document.getElementById('id').value;` don´t work.

**@charlietfl** This is the HTML code

```
<div id="editaircraftdialog" style="width: auto; min-height: 100px; height: auto;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0"><input id="id" value="foo">
<input id="editaircraft" type="submit" value="Edit Aircraft">

<div id="div2"></div></div>
```

and this is the code of the file:

```
<input id="id" value="foo"/>
<tr><td><input id="editaircraft" type="submit" value="Edit Aircraft"></td></tr>
<script>
$("#editaircraft")
                .find('button') /* ??? */
                .click(editForm);
function editForm(){
var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
$("div2").text(id);
}

</script>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: What are you using php for?

Comment: I can't really get your question.

Comment: If it doesn't work, then probably it's because there is no element with the id `id`.

Comment: php runs in server side and javascript in client side. wehn you make an ajax call the file.php runs in server side. after calling `ajaxrequest()` the inner html of `#resultdiv` will be the javascript code in file.php because it is php script's response

Comment: I need the PHP. I need use these Javascript, but It not works because is in a DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If the script in remote file is placed before the html it is looking for, it won't find it since script will run before html exists. Reversing the order of html and script will mean html exists before script tries to find it and it will work.

This is true even if code is wrapped in `document.ready`, since the `ready` event has already occurred in the main page

Also script shown in remote file is a function, but you don't ever show calling that function

Won't work:

```
<script> var id = document.getElementById('id').value;</script>
<input id="id" value="foo"/>
```

Will work:

```
<input id="id" value="foo"/>
<script> var id = document.getElementById('id').value;</script>
```

EDIT: You can also place the script in the complete callback of `load` in main page:

```
aircraft.load("./file.php?icao="+str, function(){
   /* new html now exists, run code here*/
 });
```

Comment: huh? what part of explanation isn't clear?

Comment: It doesn´t work! the var id is undefinid

Comment: post html it is looking for... is it a form element? Put html and code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: I put the HTML in the question.

Comment: there is no `button` in the html. What's that supposed to be? Also `$('div2')` is invalid selector, should be `$('#div2')`

Comment: why are you mixing jQuery , native code and inline code? just use jQuery for everything and save complicating things

Comment: also `$("#editaircraft")` has no descendents so `$("#editaircraft").find()` makes no sense either

Comment: Please, can you put a code example?

Comment: start by placing code after html... I spend time creating answer and you didn't follow it. APply click handler to proper selector. I don't even know what that is supposed to be, code is a mess. Look in selectors API to figure out what to use